# gdb: cascaded signal. info on outer one - HOWTO

Tags: c, linux, gdb, signals

Following program generates SIGSEGV from within SIGUSR1 signal handler.

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>

void sigusr_handler(int sig_number)
{
  std::cout << "hallo" << "\n";
  char *a = (char*)0x0;
  char b = *a;
  std::cout << b << "\n";
}

struct sigaction my_action;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  my_action.sa_handler = sigusr_handler;
  sigaction(SIGUSR1, &my_action, nullptr);

  sleep(1000);
  return 0;
}
```

Let's run program in gdb then send SIGUSR1 to the program.

siginfo looks like following

```
(gdb) p $_siginfo
$8 = {
  si_signo = 11, 
  si_errno = 0, 
  si_code = 1, 
  _sifields = {
    _pad = {0, 0, -1814214640, 21880, -1601342336, 32766, -1848922720, 21880, -1811928400, 21880, 0, 0, -1811928400, 21880, 176, 0, -1840786848, 21880, -1847783957, 21880, -1811928400, 21880, -1840786848, 21880, -1814214640, 21880, -1845891081, 21880}, 
    _kill = {
      si_pid = 0, 
      si_uid = 0
    }, 
    _timer = {
      si_tid = 0, 
      si_overrun = 0, 
      si_sigval = {
        sival_int = -1814214640, 
        sival_ptr = 0x557893dd4810
      }
    }, 
    _rt = {
      si_pid = 0, 
      si_uid = 0, 
      si_sigval = {
        sival_int = -1814214640, 
        sival_ptr = 0x557893dd4810
      }
    }, 
    _sigchld = {
      si_pid = 0, 
      si_uid = 0, 
      si_status = -1814214640, 
      si_utime = -6877712962820221576, 
      si_stime = -7941062615231332354
    }, 
    _sigfault = {
      si_addr = 0x0, 
      _addr_lsb = 93976365189136, 
      _addr_bnd = {
        _lower = 0x7ffea08d7480, 
        _upper = 0x557891cbada0
      }
    }, 
    _sigpoll = {
      si_band = 0, 
      si_fd = -1814214640
    }
  }
}
```

Question: is it possible to "guess" from gdb session, that outer signal was SIGUSR1?
regards,
Mat

NOTE TO STACKOVEFLOW: I have no idea what usefull notes I need to add to the above in order to have the question more usefull - IMO: more text makes the question blurred, but I'm adding some notes because I'm getting information:
"It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details" otherwise.
READERS OF POST: PLEASE FORGIVE ME.
END OF NOTE TO STACKOVERFLOW

Comment: I don't think signals are chained or nested in any way. The fact that one signal occurs while handling another signal is not represented.

Comment: You can only safely call async-signal-safe functions from within a signal handler.  Operations on `std::cout` are **not** async-signal-safe.

Answer (score 1):

> is it possible to "guess" from gdb session, that outer signal was SIGUSR1

Yes:

```
hallo

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00005555555551be in sigusr_handler (sig_number=10) at t.c:9
9         char b = *a;
(gdb) bt 
#0  0x00005555555551be in sigusr_handler (sig_number=10) at t.c:9
#1  <signal handler called>
#2  0x00007ffff775cff4 in __GI___nanosleep (requested_time=requested_time@entry=0x7fffffffdb70, remaining=remaining@entry=0x7fffffffdb70)
    at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/nanosleep.c:28
#3  0x00007ffff775cf2a in __sleep (seconds=0) at ../sysdeps/posix/sleep.c:55
#4  0x0000555555555225 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffdca8) at t.c:20
```

From this, you can clearly see that the program received `SIGSEGV` while in the handler for signal 10, which is `SIGUSR1`.

P.S. It's unclear how this question even arises: GDB should have earlier stopped and told you that `SIGUSR1` was received, like so:

```
Program received signal SIGUSR1, User defined signal 1.
0x00007ffff775cff4 in __GI___nanosleep (requested_time=requested_time@entry=0x7fffffffdb70, remaining=remaining@entry=0x7fffffffdb70) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/nanosleep.c:28
28      ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/nanosleep.c: No such file or directory.
```